# Grafana query to fetch a particular value from JSON

Tags: java, grafana, prometheus, grafana-api, grafana-variable

If I use *jvm_memory_max_bytes* it is automatically feeding the data, but I need to split up the required one to display. How can I fetch an ID with a particular value to add in a Grafana query?

```
 jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="heap", id="CMS Old Gen", instance="localhost:9090", job="myapp"}
 jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="heap", id="Par Eden Space", instance="localhost:9090", job="myapp"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the whole value to QL " jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="heap",id="CMS Old Gen",instance="localhost:9090",job="myapp"}" and name it.